# Rails Has Suddenly Stopped Working (Illinformed Argument requirement.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner to Ruby on Rails tutorials and the last thing I did was create a new app, generate scaffolding without Tests (- T flag), installed RSpec, and initiated a git repo in the folder.

That was two hours ago. I open my laptop up, try to run:

```
 rails server
```

Now I'm seeing this error:

```
/Users/reneruiz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/
  rubygems/requirement.rb:72:in 'parse': Illformed requirement ["0.7.1."] (ArgumentError)
```

The full stack trace is here: http://cl.ly/4pQC

I did some Google searches and I can't seem to find anyone else with the same problem.

I don't know how or where to go from here. Would seriously appreciate some help.

Comment: What's your Gemfile look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `Gemfile` for version requirements that look like "0.7.1." It *looks* like Bundler is trying to check for a gem with a certain version and is choking on the trailing period. If you find the version in your `Gemfile`, fix it and then run `bundle install` on the command line, and see if it'll start.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of only `bundle install` run `bundle install --full-index`